# Koahana framework, query builder

Tags: php, sql, kohana, query-builder

I've pure sql query like this:

```
SELECT concat(tyres, '-', engine, '-', body) as product, `date`, `type`, `note`
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `shop`.`users` ON `user_id` = `shop`.`user`.`id`
```

and, I using Kohana query builder in following example

```
DB::select(array(DB::expr('concat(tyres, engine, body)'), 'product'))->from('products')->join('shop'.'users','LEFT')->on('user_id', '=', 'shop.users.id');
```

so, kohana's query not working. Please help

Comment: Please describe your problem and what isn't working.

Comment: I dont' recived query return. In console is internal 500 error

Comment: You can always assign query to a variable and see compile results before suing it.   $query = DB::select ( array (
    DB::expr ( 'concat(tyres, engine, body)' ),
    'product' 
  ) )->from ( 'products' )->join ( 'shop' . 'users', 'LEFT' )->on ( 'user_id', '=', 'shop.users.id' );
  echo Debug::vars ( $query->compile() );

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use debugging to find out error.

You are join condition is wrong  you need single string to enter database name and table name. 
Replace `join('shop'.'users','LEFT')`  with `join ( 'shop.users', 'LEFT' )`

```
$query = DB::select ( array (
        DB::expr ( 'concat(tyres, engine, body)' ),
        'product' 
) )->from ( 'products' )->join ( 'shop.users', 'LEFT' )->on ( 'user_id', '=', 'shop.users.id' );
echo Debug::vars ( $query->compile () );
```

Here is out put:

```
string(125) "SELECT concat(tyres, engine, body) AS `product` FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `shop`.`users` ON (`user_id` = `shop`.`users`.`id`)"
```